How do I conditionally stop woocommerce from saving shipping/billing addresses
I'm trying to write an Address book plugin that will allow users to add multiple shipping & billing addresses to their account so they can choose an address at checkout. I need to stop woocommerce from overwriting the default shipping/billing address when they use the edit-address form so I can save the new addresses separately. I know I could create a new form with its own logic in handling form submissions/saving addresses but I would like to stick with the woocommerce edit-address form if possible.
I have tried removing the woocommerce_customer_save_address action within my own woocommerce_customer_save_address hook and I have also tried hooking into template_redirect in order to stop the processing of the form but neither of these methods have worked.
EDIT: Some of you are referring me to already existing plugins. From what I've seen, these do not support the new React powered woocommerce checkout blocks, hence why I'm developing this myself.

@RiggsFolly Pretty sure this doesn't support the new checkout block

surely this cannot be a missing feature in a tool that is so widely used

@RiggsFolly There's only 2000 active installations so I wouldn't say its widely used. I find most plugins do not support the new checkout blocks still even though its been available for a year or so now
